# Reading Text in Python and Returning a Passage of Text between Capitalised Text and an Integer

Tags: python, regex

I have a passage of text which I want to analyse.

I would like to pick out years in the text and preceding names to construct a reference list.
For example in a passage of text

```
this was discussed by Hughes et al. (2009)
```

I would like to print

```
Hughes et al. 2009.
```

I have looked at Python's regular expression module and I can find commands such as `re.findall('\d+', text)` to find my Integer values and I can use `re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*',text)` to find occurrences of a capitalized letter followed by lower case, but I don't know how to combine these into a "start/stop."

Perhaps I shouldn't even be looking at the re module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall('\d+', text)` find years, it will return string, not indexes.

Then you can iterate over `years` and do the following

```
for year in years:
    # partition(sep) divides string in three parts, 
    # (str before 'sep', `sep`, str after 'sep')
    # In your example, it would be ("this was discussed by Hughes et al. (", "2009", ")")
    preceding_text = text.partition(year)[0]

    # `r'[A-Z][a-z\s]*` would return a list of all possible matches, 
    # [-1] to get last match from the list.
    capitalized_words = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z\s]*', preceding_text)[-1]
    print(capitalized_words, year)
```

Comment: Thank youI got a "TypeError: must be str, not list".

My input was:
years = re.findall('\d+', text)
    preceding_text = text.partition(years)[0]
    capitalized_words = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z\s]*', preceding_text)[-1]
    print(capitalized_words, years)

Comment: In which line ?  Are you iterating over the result of `re.findall('\d+', text)` ?

Comment: I do not know the line.   I've got python and using notepad.  Python refers to a line number but it does not mean anything to me as my lines aren't numbered in notepad.  I just typed in the text in my last comment.  By iterating I think you mean repeating but in practise I don't know what that means in the code.  Sorry.  Thanks for your help.  The other solution works but I find that code more difficult to understand

Comment: Thank you.  This works too. 
The partition function splits the text.  Are the [0] and [-1] indices which take specific components of the tuples and lists created? Could you just briefly explain the function of the preceding_text & the capitalized_words.  I half get them.  Thank you.  This was really helpful. 

Both answers worked perfectly.  I just would like to know more so that I can do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
c = "this was discussed by Hughes et al. (2009)"

years = re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d', c)
names = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+\w*[ñáéíóúÑÁÉÍÓÚ]*\w*', c)
quotes = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+\w*[ñáéíóúÑÁÉÍÓÚ]*\w*[ .()a-z]*\d\d\d\d[)]*', c)
print years, names, quotes
```

Output:

['2009'] ['Hughes'] ['Hughes et al. (2009)']

Comment: Thanks. This worked. But I don't know why.   I get the years line, but not the names and quotes lines particularly the naeiouNAEIOU.  What does that do?

Comment: @Naz For non-English alphabet letters (examples: Peña, Noé, Fernández, Lébedev, Pávlov, etc)